# Error when tensoring with $p$-adic integers

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

It must be simple but I cannot find the error in the reasoning. Let $p$ be a prime number, we know that $\mathbb Z_p$ is flat over $\mathbb Z$ so that we can take the tensor product of the exact sequence: $$0\rightarrow \mathbb Z\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\rightarrow 0$$ with $\mathbb Z_p;$ we have the exact sequence:$$0\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow 0$$ where the last group should be zero. But multiplication by $p$ is not surjective in $\mathbb Z_p$ (the units of $\mathbb Z_p$ have no pre-image).

Comment: Why should the last group be zero? It seems pretty isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ to me...

Comment: Indeed... not all elements in $\mathbb Z_p$ are multiple of $p$. So it should be $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Exactly right; the first map isn't surjective because not all elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are multiples of $p$, and the last group isn't trivial because not all elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are multiples of $p$. Though it may be worth while to write up an explicit map
$$\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Z}_p\cong\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z},$$
and prove that it is an isomorphism.